# Do processes terminate when terminal is closed?

Tags: linux, process, fork

In the `parent > child process` relationship, done with fork(), I have read the following:

> If the parent is killed, children become children of the init process (that has the process id 1 and is launched as the first user process by the kernel).

When I run a program using the terminal it forks and executes a new binary.
Why is that when I close the terminal the child process also terminates? According to the above
info, why does it not become a child of the root process?

I have also read:

> When you close bash with normal exit it triggers SIGHUP hangup signal to all its jobs.

So what happens at the end of the day? it becomes child of root process or dies? These statements contract each other.

Comment: Read about [process groups and sessions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group). One of the things that can happen is the process tries to write to the terminal, gets an error, and terminates itself.

Comment: There are no contradiction here. One quote says: *If the parent process exits, the child process assigned to 1*, the second quote says: *interactive bash kills (with SIGHUP) all child processes on exit*. If child survives (see my answer below), then it will be assigned to pid 1.

Answer (score 0):

When a terminal is closed, then shell, which is running in the terminal, receives a SIGHUP. This signal is 'broadcasted' to all processes (child processes) started in that shell. As SINGHUP is by default a [Termination Signal](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html#Termination-Signals), the program is aborted, if no addition actions are taken.

An application can be started with *nohup* (man nohup) command to be SIGHUP resistant, or set it's own signal handler.

Comment: but the question is why doesn't each process become a child of the root process, isn't it supposed to?

Comment: As it receives SIGHUP, the default behavior is to die. If there is a signal handler and process did not exit, then parent pid is set to 1.

Comment: @Josh How did you establish that it didn't? Did you observe a time where its parent was dead, it was alive, and it wasn't a child of the root process? If not, how do you know what would or would not have happened in that case?

Comment: If the parent and child are killed by the same event, then the child will become a zombie, but *will* still become a child of 'init'. It'll be cleaned up within milliseconds though, so you'll never see it.